# View T-SQL in CLR Assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr

I have a production database with numerous scalar functions. My goal is to create set based alternatives for reporting. Unfortunately, I don't have a good way to view the T-SQL actually being executed because the functions reference a CLR assembly. Is there a good way to view the T-SQL inside the assembly for each function?

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL *being* executed is different than T-SQL that *will be* executed if the function is run.

- To see what is currently executing, you would use either SQL Server Profiler, or Extended Events. Then you can execute a function and see what T-SQL it runs.
- To see what the function *might* execute, that is a bit trickier. You do have the code in the `sys.assembly_files` system catalog view. The `content` field contains the binary representation of the assembly. But, to see the code you need to find a way to extract it  to a binary file (no built-in method, and no, not a text file containing that "binary" string) and then decompile it.

  String literals should be contained as-is in the assembly, so theoretically you should be able to convert the `VARBINARY` value in `sys.assembly_files.content` to `NVARCHAR`, but there are two problems there:

  1. Queries can be constructed from several literals and/or variables, so it's hard to say if viewing this would be conclusive, and
  2. There are many `0x00` bytes, and those will stop the displaying of what comes after it because it is the "null" terminator for strings, so you need to find a way to convert those to spaces (while also not converting a trailing `0` of one byte followed by a leading `0` of the next byte).

So, perhaps just use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see what T-SQL is submitted when the functions are executed.